# dynamic constant name

Tags: php, constants

I have a little problem with a dynamic constant name declaration.
I can't find out why the expression defining $constName is not correctly evaluated:

Here is my code:

```
$type2 = "type2";
$env = "env";

$constName = "test_$type2_$env";
return constant(__CLASS__."::$constName");
```

After that, I don't get the correct value : test_type2_env, but this instead: test_env

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$constName = "test_{$type2}_$env";
```

Because PHP understands that you want the value of the 'type2_' variable.